# Non standard hub bearing?

Tags: hub, bearings

I need to replace a hub bearing. On it, I can Read ZPL (manufacturer I guess) and 6200RS. 6200 seems to be a standard for (inner diameter x outer diameter x width) 10 x 30 x 9mm. But when I measure, I get 12.65 x 28.75 x 9.00 mm.

My measurement tool is accurate, I've tripled-checked it.

It is not because the bearing is worn out on the outside and inside, since the bearing fits perfectly on the axis and the hub.

I bought the bike second hand, it was imported from Tokyo, I live in France.

How do I replace the piece? I cannot find any bearing with similar measurements and a standard 6200 surely won't fit.

[image]

Comment: what is the hub? brand/model will help.. sometimes manufacturers ship hubs with bearings that don't line up with the numbers on the shield and the bearing could be available from the manufacturer. Also is this a front hub? if rear, is this inside the hub flange? freehub?

Comment: It may help to understand what's going on here that the info from the seal actually should be taken to just describe the seal itself. Sometimes bike and parts makers do get weirdo custom bearings made for whatever reason that are made to use an off the shelf seal. When I've encountered this there's been no recourse but to go to the manufacturer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like the bearing has the wrong dust shield.  Sizing lines up closer to an imperial(inches) sizing, 1/2"x1 1/8" x 3/8"ish.  The inside and outside diameters are close, the width is less important than the ID and OD as you typically have a preload adjustment on the axle.  Try a 1616-2RS (9.5mm wide) or a R8-2RS (8mm) bearing.

Alternatively, If the bearing is simply feeling rough, you can remove the dust cover with a knife, clean out the bearing with alcohol and repack with a marine grade grease.  This may improve the smoothness if the races are not too pitted/corroded and add a bit more life to the bearing.

Comment: What do you do when the dust cover becomes so old that the rubber is essentially melting off so the dust cover will no longer snap into place? By the way, welcome to bicycles, looking forward to more great answers.

Comment: right, I had looked up the size with imperial sizing and thought it didn't make sense, but forgot imperial units are often expressed as ratios. The 1616-2RS does have a pretty close sizing. I've already changed the hub, but good to know I'll probably be able to still use the old one!

Comment: @Rider_X If the rubber is at that stage its probably time for a new bearing!